# Identity Framework Add User and use in same method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a call that will create a new user if they enter a password when purchasing the product. If they create an account I then have to update the data to be reflected to that user. But the problem I am having is I am not able to use that user in the same call and have not been able to figure out how to update the Identity Framework to be able to recognized the newly created user. If the page is refreshed and tried again it works, but the first time it creates an error... because there is no user.

It saves the data in the AspNetUsers table. The newUser object has an assigned user. But I am not able to use that object either. I tried pulling the newUser object out and assigning the newUser object but it then tries to create a new user with the same ID and I get foreign key errors. I am not sure how to make it so I can use the newly created user in the same call.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CheckoutStep2(CheckoutStep2ViewModel model)

  if (model.Password != null && model.PasswordConfirm != null)
  {
    ApplicationUser newUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.PaymentInformation.BillingEmail, Email = model.PaymentInformation.BillingEmail };
    var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
      await signInManager.SignInAsync(newUser, isPersistent: false);
    }
  }

  // THIS CALL NEVER RETRIEVES THE NEWLY CREATED USER
  ApplicationUser user = 
  this.commonDataAccess.GetCurrentUser(User.Identity.Name);

  // IRREVERENT DATA REMOVED

}
```

**GetCurrentUser**

```
public ApplicationUser GetCurrentUser(string userName)
{
  return context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);
}
```

Comment: What data are you trying to get for the user that you don't already have in `ApplicationUser` object?

Comment: All the data was there... but when I assigned the user on a new object it would track it as a new add and try to add it again and I was getting Foreign Key errors. So I had to go back and get the ApplicationUser from the database again so Entity would properly track it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get User.Identity.Name to recognized a logged in user. So instead I created a new call to get a user by the ID and just pass the newly created ID into the call to get a user from the database that is tracked in the Entity Graph (Foreign Key Issues)

**Working Call**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CheckoutStep2(CheckoutStep2ViewModel model) {

  ApplicationUser user = null;
  if (model.Password != null && model.PasswordConfirm != null)
  {
    user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.PaymentInformation.BillingEmail, Email = model.PaymentInformation.BillingEmail };
    var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
      await signInManager.SignInAsync(newUser, isPersistent: false);
    }
  }

  // THIS CALL NEVER RETRIEVES THE NEWLY CREATED USER
  user = this.commonDataAccess.GetUserById(user.Id);


  ....IRREVERENT DATA REMOVED    
}
```